# Accessing all the elments of a specific key in list of dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this.

```
data1 = {"00:08:22:24:f8:02":
        {"cities" : 
               [
                 {'name': 'Bhubaneswar', 'count': 12, 'date':14/05/2016},
                 {'name': 'Kolkata', 'count': 4, 'date': 15/05/2016},
                 {'name': 'Mumbai', 'count': 6, 'date' : 16/04/2016}
            ]}
     }
```

I want to check

1. if string var(say) matches with a value to the key 'name'
2. if a variable x(say), of type date, matches with a value to the key 'date'

in the list of dictionaries inside the dictionary data1.

Comment: Your explanation of your issue isn't easily understandable. Could your please provide the desired output for a desired input?.

Comment: Can you provide concrete output for sample input in both cases? Description is rather unclear.

Comment: I don't understand. You know how to get the values from the dictionary. So you seem to be asking how to check if a string has a substring, and whether a date is after another date. So you could delete the dictionary part of your question and just search for answers to the other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know the exact format that you wanted to achieve I had to make some fairly pronounced guess work. I hope this helps in anyway. Good luck

```
import datetime
data1 = {"00:08:22:24:f8:02": 
                            {"cities" : 
                                        [{'name': 'Bhubaneswar', 'count': 12, 'date':'14/05/2016'},
                                         {'name': 'Kolkata', 'count': 4, 'date': '15/05/2016'},
                                         {'name': 'Mumbai', 'count': 6, 'date' : '16/04/2016'}]
                             }
         }
#first issue with your origonal data, cities would actually become a dict based on your origonal data

def get_name(dict, name, hash=None, position=None):
    '''
        :arg dict is your data set
        :arg name is the name you want to check for
        :arg hash is the first index of your dict
        :arg position is the 2nd index of your dict
        :returns return the first object that contains name
        '''

    if name and hash and position:
        for i, v in enumerate(dict[hash][position]):
            try:
                if name in v['name']:
                    return dict[hash][position][i]
            except:
                pass
    else:
        for hash, v in dict.iteritems():
            for position, v2 in v.iteritems():
                for i, index in enumerate(v2):
                    for field, v3 in index.iteritems():
                        if name in str(v3):
                            return index

    return {}

def is_date_greater(dict, date):
    '''
        :arg dict is your data set
        :arg date is the date you want to compare with
        :returns True if date is greater than the supplied date
        '''

    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y')
    try:
        n_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dict['date'], '%d/%m/%Y')
        if date < n_date:
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False

print is_date_greater(get_name(data1, 'Bhub'), '12/4/16')
```

Comment: I have to update a dict. from a data frame. I have defined the logic something like this.
`def fun(mac, city, date):
  if mac in dic.keys():
    flag=0
    for city in dic[mac]:
      if city['city']==city:
        if date>city['date']:
          city['count']+=1
          city['date']=date
          flag=1
          break
    if flag==0:
      dic[mac].append({"city":city, "count":1, "date":date})
  else:
    dic[mac]=[]
    dic[mac].append({"city":city, "count":1, "date":date})`

Dataframe have 3 rows named 'mac' , 'city' , 'date' and dictionary is same as above.

Comment: So I am having problem in checking `city in dic[mac]` and further line as I have to check exactly for that dictionary containing the 'city' and then check for that dictionary's date further.

Comment: I really dont understand how is this solving my problem. Thanks for your help, it will be pretty nice if I can discuss with you.

Comment: You can join this chat room on SO an I could attempt to assist you further! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114590/question-help